# Conectar PostgreSQL no Delphi 7 através do ZeosLib

Tags: postgresql, delphi-7, zeos

Estou tentando conectar o PostgreSQL no Delphi 7, encontrei em um fórum a ideia de utilizar o ZeosLib para realizar essa conexão assistindo a uma vídeo aula cheguei a essa configuração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém mesmo seguindo passo a passo de como configurar, sempre que tento realizar a conexão a seguinte janela de erro ocorre:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão de o que pode estar ocorrendo?

Comment: Segundo essa [tread](http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/viewtopic.php?t=28657), seu cliente não possui suporte ao método de autenticação. Você pode alterar a versão do cliente ou alterar o método de autenticação no arquivo [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Comment: E qual seria a alteração que eu teria que fazer neste arquivo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema após a ajuda do @Marcelo de Andrade referente ao arquivo *pg_hba.conf*, pesquisei e descobri que o erro poderia estar na linha:

**host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5**

e que precisaria editar para:

**host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password**

Depois desta alteração o erro não ocorreu mais.

Comment: Então marque sua resposta como aceita

Comment: @durtto Eu só posso aceitar minha resposta a partir de amanhã

Comment: rs, tudo bem...